# How to achieve a work around for the css position: fixed in IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, background, media-queries

I have placed the proper media screen queries and it works fine on the desktop (as I change the viewport size); however, when I bring it up on my iPhone 4s all the backgrounds disappear.
I believe that the problem is that IOS does not support the css of position: fixed. I have done tons of research and have not found an adequate solution, does anyone have any ideas to a solution for this?

Here is my CSS:

```
/* Desktop */
#home{width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: url(../images/landingPage.png) no-repeat fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;}

#about{width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: url(../images/about.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;}
```

(There are four more sections with all the same mark-up.)

```
/* Mobile */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px){

#home{height: 960px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;}
#about{height: 960px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;}
```

(There are four more sections with all the same mark-up.)

Comment: No it is not inside a media screen query.

Comment: yeah....it is only on the mobile device. iamparisjones.com/newsite

Comment: I don't have an answer, but your background looks weird on narrower screens; it gets stretched. Didn't you mean `background-size: cover` instead of `100% 100%`? Also, you include your master.css before your reset.css. Switch those around.